# Pass a variable to text_field without changing form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

I have _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
```

Now if I render this form in homepage, HTML code should be:

```
<label for="session_name">Name</label>
<input id="session_name" name="session[name]" size="30" type="text">
...
```

If I change my _form.html.erb to:

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, disabled: true %>
...
```

HTML code should be:

```
...
<input disabled="disabled" id="session_name" name="session[name]" size="30" type="text">
...
```

But, I don't want to change my _form.html.erb, so how can I pass the `disabled: true` into my form? I tried to use `render partial:` but don't know syntax.

I just learn Ruby on Rails for 2 weeks, so please help me.

Comment: i don't understand what you can't do. The raw problem is quite easy, explain your constraints better

Answer (score 0):

i donno why u wnt to do so but u can solve the prob by this method. Try doing-

in application helper, add method -

```
def add_disabled
  #i suppose that u want the field to be disabled in the users controller for edit action but not for other controllers or actions
  return "disabled='disabled'" if params[:controller] == "users" and params[:action] == "edit"
end
```

in _form.html.haml

```
= f.text_field :name, #{add_disabled}
```

this will call the helper method and return "**disabled='disabled'**" depending upon the controller and action

Comment: Thank you.
That's exactly what I want to do, disable name field in edit action.
Btw, is render patial: can do it ?

Comment: any helper method will be called from the partial too. Also, helper method names should be uniq throughout all the helpers. So if u want this functionality across different actions for different controllers, add the helper method in application helper.

Comment: Just abit ajust to make it work in my app,
in `add_disabled` method:

`return { disabled: true }`

, and in _form.html.erb :

`= f.text_field :name, add_disabled`